# Appending same element to two dropdowns results in only the last being appended

Tags: javascript, append, html-select

I have the following code;

```
    function SetupDropdowns() {
        var PrevType;

        dropdown1 = document.getElementById("ddl1");
        ******************
        for (var i = 0; i < Cars.length; i++) {
            var myItem = Items[i];
            if (PrevType != myItem.grouping) {
                var seperator = document.createElement("option");
                seperator.textContent = "----- " + myItem.grouping + " ------";
                seperator.value = "";
                seperator.disabled = true;
                dropdown1.appendChild(seperator);
                **********************
                PrevType = myItem.grouping;
            }

            var NewOption = document.createElement("option");
            NewOption.textContent = myItem.Name;
            NewOption.value = myItem.SomeProperty;
            dropdown1.appendChild(NewOption);
            *********************
```

This works great; however once I add the following 3 lines (in the * positions) the first drop down is no longer appended to.

```
       dropdown2 = document.getElementById("ddl2");
                dropdown2.appendChild(seperator);
       dropdown2.appendChild(NewOption);
```

With these lines added, the lines are appended only to the second select and not the first.

Surely this new element should be appended to both options, or can it only be appended to one and a second element must be created for the second select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NewOption` is one element. When the element is appended, it's moved not cloned. You should either create 2 options or clone the first one. What's happening now is you append the option to the first select element and immediately move it into the second select element.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to create a new element or to clone the element in order to add it twice in the DOM. Like:

```
var NewOption_copy = NewOption.cloneNode(true);
dropdown2.appendChild(NewOption_copy);
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining how to clone the element, I would love to make this the accepted answer but the other answer addresses the why it happens and how to address it (granted without the code). Thanks again